# Filling No Instances using Value Counts with 0 - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I created a dataframe from valuecounts()[False] looking for all instance where false occured.
However i have since ran into the issue of if no [False] i get the output of "True 110 Name: B_CHECK, dtype: int64".

How can i fix this?

**Code:**

```
masterdf

A_CHECK_false_count = (masterdf['A']).value_counts()[False]
B_CHECK_false_count = (masterdf['B']).value_counts()[False] #NO INSTANCES OF FALSE IN COLUMN B
C_CHECK_false_count = (masterdf['C']).value_counts()[False]

d = {'A_CHECK_Total': [A_CHECK_false_count], 
     'B_CHECK_Total': [B_CHECK_false_count], 
     'C_CHECK_Total': [C_CHECK_false_count]}

FalseCountCheck = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

| A_Check_Total | B_Check_Total | C_Check_Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 67 | True 110 Name: B_CHECK, dtype: int64 | 13 |

Comment: Can you please share an example of `masterdf` that allows us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: what does `.value_counts()[False]` mean!! this is not a valid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `df`:

```
       A     B      C
0   True  True  False
1   True  True  False
2  False  True  False
```

Doing:

```
out = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].eq(False).sum().to_frame().T.add_suffix('_Check_Total')
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   A_Check_Total  B_Check_Total  C_Check_Total
0              1              0              3
```

Comment: this was perfect. rush job in creating this question but you did assume correctly. .valuecount()[False] only go me so far. thanks for the help!